# Camera focal length settings to match a Kinect

Tags: camera, tracking

I have a question about the camera setting in the movie clip editor.
I am trying to copy the characteristics of a Kinect camera in Blender, but do not have much knowledge in photography.
All I know is that Focal Length must be 525. I configured this value in Blender, but the result is not right.

I changed the *Width* of the Camera Sensor to see what happens and obtained a different outcome. But I have no idea what values I should set (and if it is really this setting that I should change) to the camera to correspond to the real one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the specs found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131033.aspx) the Kinect has a horizontal viewing angle of 57 degrees.

Set your camera accordingly in the lens section:

[image]

Comment: That's it? Thaks a lot, man!